# Как разделить на разные файлы несколько моделей blender?

Tags: blender

У меня есть файл .blender, в котором находятся несколько моделей с материалами, костями и прочим. Нужно раскидать эти модели по разным .fbx файлам без танцев с бубном. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В настройках экспорта есть возможность экспортировать только выделенное (Selected Objects):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]